# git - How do remove a file that came in a merge?

Tags: git

On a branch (say b1) I merged stuff from b2. After some work I merged b1 into b3. Then I realized I didn't wanted that merge, so in b3 I reseted hard to a previous commit and pushed that. Now my problem is I still find files from the branch b2 in b3. How can I remove this files? And why are they still in b3?

Note: on a not so distant future I'll need to merge b3 into b2.

Comment: In what sense are the files from b2 still in b3? Are they just in your sandbox, or are they actually in the commit tree?

Comment: They are in the commit tree

Comment: Then I would examine the output of `git log --graph --annotate --stat`, you might find the explanation for what happened.

Comment: You need to show, what sequence of commands you applied exactly. See e.g. [git-doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-Undocommitspermanently)